# How to create Interactive World Map with all the countries in Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, svg, world-map

I want to Create a World Map of countries with interactive features like selection,color coding and customizing legends. What is the right approach to do this?If there is any such library already, do post links.

**Update**

So finally I am using androidsvg library to load the SVG file. I got the worldmap svg file from wikimedia. The SVG file was around 2.4Mb . Hence it takes sometime to render. It worked perfectly. Sadly there is no tutorial/sample app that describes the other important aspect of using SVG i.e Scaling(zooming options), even handling(onClick Events). Etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out. 
Openstreet maps. This is a very good library and probably this will do. 
http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/ 
But also this is nice lib but paid. 
http://mapp.android-libraries.com/download 
And one another to help you out 
http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/

Comment: Do you suggest he loads this via a Webview then?

Comment: @Katana24 No sorry my mistake. Updated libraries

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently using OpenLayers in a web application project. It's very good. Looks there is now support for it on mobile devices

[OpenLayers in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823216/openlayers-in-android)

Comment: was just about to ask how you intent for him to use it in Android - was going to ask if you meant to use it through a webview

Comment: Yes, good question. Openlayers is very much designed for use in a web browser context. I'm not aware of any pure Android libraries to do this.

Comment: [android-svg](https://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/) could be used to load the SVG file . But I am not sure how to handle the onClick events and changing colour based on path id.